# Workflow to anonymise / mask data in production database from devs

Tags: mysql, sql, database, anonymity, anonymize

Our production database contains confidential information, that we dont want our developers to see.

Is there a normal workflow to get around this confidentially issue, without majorly impacting on the developers workflows / ability to trouble shoot.

We are using mysql 5.x

Comment: Sure, create a dev database that has junk data in it.

Comment: Usually that is handled either via contract as in Non-Disclosure agreement or you only provide them dummy data.

Comment: We had this sort of problem working for a big insurance company. We had developers that were to verify bug reports from production... these were under NDA (most were employees of the insurance company) and would actually have access to production data. Other developers working on development and test environments would have dummy data. There was a system test environment that had a copy of all the production data pumped in during the night... but sensible information would be mocked by the copy procedure (it had a parametric list of tables/fields that had to be cleansed).

Comment: you could create a `VIEW` [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-view.html) for each table where you randomize `rand()` every named content but still keep keys